# Kotlin nested sealed classes for mapping enums

Tags: kotlin, enums, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

I have an extensive class hierarchy that I want to map to an existing enum type. Given this example hierarchy:

```kotlin
open class A {
    open class BB: A() {
        class CCC: BB(){}
        class DDD: BB(){}
    }
}
```

I want to map the class type from the hierarchy to the enum, i.e. in kotlin a mapping of type

```kt
val mapping: Pair<KClass<A>, TypeEnum> = A::class to TypeEnum.TYPEA
```

I thought to use a sealed class for each hierarchy class that contains the corresponding mapping, I have this code, but isn't working as the compiler says I can't instantiate a sealed class

```kt
sealed class ASealed(type: KClass<out A>) {

        abstract val typeMapping: TypeEnum

        sealed class BBSealed(type: KClass<out BB>) : ASealed(type) {

            override val typeMapping = TypeEnum.TYPEBB

            sealed class CCCSealed(type: KClass<CCC>) : BBSealed(type){
                override val typeMapping = TypeEnum.TYPECCC
            }
            sealed class DDDSealed(type: KClass<DDD>) : BBSealed(type){
                override val typeMapping = TypeEnum.TYPEDDD
            }

        }
}

fun mapto(){
    val ccc = CCC()
    val enum = ASealed(ccc::class).typeMapping
}
```

Is it possible to use this approach, so I have all the class hierarchy grouped and retrieve the enum type like in the above function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by marking it `sealed`?

Comment: Like Tenfour04 asks, why `sealed`?  Sealed is generally used to reason about the class hierarchy - so the compiler can, e.g. know all cases are are handled in a `when( )` what takes a class arg.  But you seem to want external instrumentation of  your classes.  Therefore isn't it sufficient to enforce the `typeMapping` by requiring the classes to implement an interface e.g.  `interface WithType { typeMapping: TypeEnum }`